# does not contain a constructor that takes '13' arguments array

Tags: c#

```
public class TestClass
{
    public string TestName;
    public double Pressure;
    public int FLOW;
    public int[] Timer = new int[10];

    public TestClass(string TN, double P, int F, int[] Time)
    {
        TestName = TN;
        Pressure = P;
        FLOW = F;
        Time = Timer;
    } 
}

public static TestClass[] TestProgram = new TestClass[]
{
    new TestClass("Test Name 01", 5.0, 50, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
    new TestClass("Test Name 02", 10.0, 70, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
};
```

Hello, I am writing the above code in a .cs file (variables.cs) & I want to access the values in different c# forms.

I am working with classes for the first time, in fact trying!,  I get the error
  "does not contain a constructor that takes '13' arguments array", 
if I remove the array part "int[] Time" the code runs, basically I am writing array part incorrectly, Please help me .

Comment: The error message tells you pretty much exactly what the problem is - you're trying to pass 13 arguments to your constructor.

Comment: Are you aware that you are assigning an empty array to your parameter `Time` inside your constructor? I believe you are trying to do exactly the opposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options, either pass an array:

```
new TestClass(..., new int [] { .....})
```

Or, which in my opinion is nicer, let the compiler put all the arguments in an array. Define your constructor like this:

```
public TestClass(string TN, double P, int F, params int[] Time) ...
```

Note the `params`. This tells the computer to group all the arguments after F into one integer array.

Comment: Thanks for reply "params" method seems to work, but what will be the solution if in case there are 2 or more arrays

Comment: You will need to pass the arrays explicitly.